# HTML tag parsing extracting title and others

Tags: java, html, parsing, bufferedreader

trying to extract title from website, when printing title i get a stream closed error. trying to extract between title tags such as  . not familiar wit parsing please be thorough when explaining. thanks.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;




public class Allrecipes{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{  


    System.out.println("Colby Mehmen");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str1 = "";
    str1 = compare();

    if (str1.contains("http://allrecipes.com")){



        URL oracle = new URL(str1);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String html;
        while ((html = in.readLine()) != null)  

            in.close();




     String page = html;

     int start = page.indexOf("<title>");
     int end = page.indexOf("</title>");

String title = page.substring(start+"<title>".length(),end);

System.out.println(title);


    }//end program





  }
```

Comment: It would be great if you formatted your code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry in a rush, cleaned up a little

Comment: java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: ^ error i am now recieving

Comment: See my updated answer, would appreciate if you accept that answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JSoup

Try [JSOUP API](http://jsoup.org) it is really easy to use

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(YOUR_WEBSITE).get();
Elements tt = doc.select("title");
System.out.println(tt.text());
```

---

### Your code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Allrecipes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Colby Mehmen");

    // http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Cardamom-Maple-Salmon/Detail.aspx?soid=carousel_0_rotd&prop24=rotd

    String str1 = "";
    str1 = compare();

    if (str1.contains("http://allrecipes.com")) {

        URL oracle = new URL(str1);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                oracle.openStream()));

        String html = null;
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            html += line;

        in.close();

        String page = html;

        int start = page.indexOf("<title>");
        int end = page.indexOf("</title>");

        String title = page.substring(start+7, end);
        System.out.println(title);

    }// end program

}

public static String compare() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter recipe URL: ");
    String str1 = input.next();
    String str2 = "allrecipes.com";
    String str3 = "http://";

    boolean b = str1.contains(str2);

    if (b == true) {
        boolean c = str1.contains(str3 + str2);

        if (c == false) {
            str1 = str3 + str1;

        }
    }// endifif

    boolean d = str1 != str3 + str2;
    if (d == false) {

        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }

    /* cOUT */System.out.println(str1);

    return str1;
}// end compare

}
```

Comment: when i use the above code it says  cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Document

Comment: you need to add JSoup library first

Comment: okay when i fixed that i printed out title and still got repeating 0's

Comment: I don't know about your code, JSOUP will return the title *as-is*, if it has zeros then it will return zeros, really I don't understand your problem

Comment: im not sure if i can use Jsoup. do i just need to use imports cause ive tried before

Comment: Okay, so I am doing your homework ... Anyyway: You receive 0's because you output x, which is always 0 and you never change it. I will edit my answer with a new code in a sec.

Comment: yes i realised i was printing x and i edited the code above now, and i receive a java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: Your JSoup API link is broken. You probably meant [jsoup.org](http://jsoup.org/).